# That's it vs. That's all (= There is no step three)

Tags: phrase-choice, sentence-choice

From an old advertisement by Apple:

> Presenting three easy steps to the Internet. Step one: plug in. Step 2: Get connected. Step three: there is no step three.

What would be the correct phrase to use here, *that's it*, *that's all*, *done*, or something else?

- **That's it.** There's no step three.
- **That's all.** There's no step three.
- **Done.** There's no step three.

I'm actually interested in writing technical documentation, not advertisements.

Comment: Or *That's your lot!* - this is just an Off Topic beauty contest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So both "that's it" and "that's all" are equally fine when we need to denote the end of sequence of some steps? I'm actually interested in writing technical documentation, not advertisements.

Comment: That's not a 'technical documentation'. It's an informal advertisement. The third step is a joke. There are only two really.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. The cited text is a *joke*. Effectively, it's a *spoof* of "writing technical documentation". But I would just add that ending with *That's it!* is "chatty Internet clickbait style", rather than "technical documentation".

Comment: It's also a hark-back to Monty Python's "Michael Baldwin, Bruce" Australian sketch. "Rule six. There is ***no*** … … rule six. Rule seven…"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reasonably formal style suitable for technical documentation you should use **nothing at all**.

> There are two steps to get internet:
>
> 1. Plug in
> 2. Get connected

You don't say "That's it" or anything else.  I don't need anything to denote the end of a sequence.  I know when the sequence ends without needing to be told.

In an informal conversation I might add "and that's it" or "and that's all". Not to denote the end of the sequence, but to emphasise my opinion that it was a short, or simple task. Technical documentation should avoid making jokes like "there is no step 3"

Comment: It has become a bit of a meme ever since, though, in 'ad-speak' rather than 'technical manual'